# Writing text in superscript in ios

Tags: ios, superscript

I am dynamically setting text of the `UITableView` title `Label` from an array. Array consists of number of strings. I want text character in `superstring` format. So how can I do that in `ios`.

Array is :

```
quality=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1080pHD",@"720pHD",@"480p",@"360p",@"240p",@"144p", nil];
```

I want HD in superscript.

Thank You,

Comment: I had tried unicode value, eg. : \u00B2 this will write 2 as a superscript. But i want HD as a superscript.

Comment: There were two recent questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18001574/how-to-subscript-letters-when-not-there-is-no-glyph-in-system-font) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17957163/how-to-add-table-view-section-header-with-subscripts) about how to implement subscripts that were pretty similar.

Comment: esker : Those are for writing numeric digit in superscript/subscript, for which i got an answer as unicode value. But i want character in superscript.

Comment: This can be done with `NSAttributedString`, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8555777/2462469